# Git: Pushing new branch to a peer

Tags: git

My workplace recently switched from SVN to Git, and I'm trying to figure a few things out. I know a bit more than the average person wrt Git already, but I'm still having problems.

So it was decided that my manager's local repo will be the "official" repository for our joint work on this new project (not allowed to push to official repo yet, even with branches). He ran **git daemon** so I can pull from him, but I'm having issues pushing. Can I even do this?

I created a new branch with new feature code, and have tried pushing to him using `git push -u newremote path/to/branch` and it's stuck on **Writing objects: 30%**. There are no large files being pushed.

Does he need to be pulling from me, or can I push to him?

Answer (score 0):

looks like he is missing some setup, Checkout this tutorial specifically Sharing push access... http://railsware.com/blog/2013/09/19/taming-the-git-daemon-to-quickly-share-git-repository/

Comment: Seems that's not the case. The instructions that we were given include the read/write permissions, yet it's still not working.